# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (java)

Tags: java

I am trying to replace a jar file after it's been added to the class path programmatically. 
When I try to replace a jar that's been loaded, it gives me the subject error.

I'm using Windows 8 , and JDK 7.

Any suggestions or workaround is highly appreciated.

error line

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(sourcePath), Paths.get(desPath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

exception

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\test\test.jar
> D:\project\plugins\test.jar
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:205)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1225)
    at org.test.Test.apply(Test.java:89)
```

Comment: what type of error you are getting. update your question with stacktrace for a better picture

Comment: the error message is quite self-explanatory. when a jar 's been loaded, it can't be removed. it's like trying to delete a word document that you are currently working in. not possible.

Comment: It's working in linux, but not in windows.

Comment: I though this was suppose to have been fixed in java 7, the ClassLoader keeping the jars open after it's loaded them, might be a windows "feature"

Comment: Can you please put the java code here so that others can try.

Comment: jars are added to the class path using a bat file, It's kind of a large project, I can't add all the files, since there is a large flow.

Comment: take a look at [Closing a URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/ClassLoader.html), *"However, since it can't be predicted exactly when finalization and garbage collection will occur, problems are caused for applications which need to be able to do this in a predictable and timely fashion. It is a problem on Windows, because open files cannot be deleted or replaced."*

Comment: It works on Linux because on Linux the process that uses the file will have access to the file, even if it is deleted, as long as the process is running (I believe `ps` can even show "deleted but still in use"-files per process). Only when the process stops or lets go of the file, the file is 'permanently' deleted and disk free space increases. I.e. you can change a file used by a process, but the process will not use the changed file unless the file is re-opened.